# Rectangle does not fill height with other components in Layout [QML]

Tags: qt, qml

This is what I have

[image: What I have]

This is what I want

[image: What I want]

my qml :

```
ColumnLayout
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    anchors.bottomMargin: 10
    anchors.rightMargin: 10
    anchors.leftMargin: 10
    spacing: 10
    
    Rectangle
    {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color : "#600000"
        border : 20
    }
    Button
    {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        text: "Button1" 
    }
    Button
    {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        text: "Button2" 
    }
}
```

The problem with the above layout, is that I want the Rectangle to fill 1/3 of the screen. Right now it fills maybe only 10 pixels worth of height. When I have several components in a layout, I personally expect them to fill each as much as the other. Since I know I will add more button, remove others, I **don't** want to just take the `Layout.preferredHeight : parent.height/3`. this will require lots of maintenance long term.

another thing I don't understand : 2 rectangle together will separate their space half half. 2 buttons will do the same. But as soon as I mix those two components, the button seem to take 95% of the height as opposed to the rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button` has `implicitHeight` defined automatically while `Rectangle` doesn't so `Layout.fillHeight` is not working as you wanted.

One sulotion would be to determine the size by the parent, I.e:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Rectangle{
    anchors.fill: parent;

    color: "grey"
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        spacing: 10

        Rectangle{
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "#600000"
            implicitHeight: parent.height / 3
        }

        Button{

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "Button1"
            implicitHeight: parent.height / 3
        }

        Button{
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "Button2"
            implicitHeight: parent.height / 3
        }
    }
}
```

Another would be to override the `implicitHeight` property of `Button` like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent;

    color: "grey"
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        spacing: 10

        Rectangle{
            id: rect1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "#600000"
        }

        Button{
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "Button1"
            implicitHeight: rect1.implicitHeight
        }

        Button{
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "Button2"
            implicitHeight: rect1.implicitHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is unfortunately what I'm trying to avoid, as many more labels, buttons and other components will be removed and added again. I want to avoid maintenance long term.
the other thing is I want to make visible and invisible some component at runtime, which means I want the layout to resize automatically with the visible components.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `ListView` or  a `Repeater`

Comment: There is no way for `Items` inside a layout to know what the size they should be in, That is the responsibility of the user to determine.

Comment: I see... thanks. I thought maybe there was some possible hack, like putting the rectangle inside another container, or something that would make the rectangle be interpreted just like a button for the columnLayout.

Comment: Other solution Would be to create a C++ component that will set the implicit width of his siblings by the interval you set.

Comment: @asdfasdf Re: "ike putting the rectangle inside another container"
In that case theier size would vary if i.e the text was longer. I don't think that's what you seek.

Comment: @asdfasdf I have added another solution, see if it fits you.

Comment: thanks, your second solution was the hack I took. I created a custom button with a "default" `implicitHeight` of 0. I don't really understand the relation between `implicitHeight` and `layout.fillHeight`, but I will read more about it. 

In my head, the point of `layout.fill` is to ignore that `implicitHeight` no?

Comment: if `implicitHeight` is set it would be the largest height the item can be, therefore `fillHeight` is ignored.. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitHeight-prop)

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned by @ניר the issue is that the `Button`s have an `implicitHeight` set. If a `ColumnLayout` has multiple children with `Layout.fillHeight` set to `true`, it will use their `implicitHeight` or `Layout.preferredHeight` as a "weight" to distribute the remaining height (see [QtQuick Layouts Overview: Size Constraints](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#size-constraints)).
In your case you can do what you want by setting a fixed preferredHeight for all the children, no need to reference the parent or one of the siblings:

```
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "grey"
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            spacing: 10

            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 1
                color : "#600000"
            }
            Button {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 1
                text: "Button1"
            }
            Button {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 1
                text: "Button2"
            }
        }
    }
```